# Angular Material | Change mat-stepper animation to fadeIn <-> fadeOut

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm using [Angular Material mat-stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) in my application.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [@.disabled]="true">
  <mat-step> Some content here with height=500px </mat-step>
  <mat-step> Some different content here with height=250px </mat-step>
  <mat-step> Other content with height=750px, you get the point </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

The default slide animation (when changing steps) are not suitable for my need.

Im aware that setting `[@.disabled]="true"` in the `mat-horizontal-stepper` html tag disables the animation.

**Question:** Is it possible to change the animation to a fadeIn/fadeOut animation?

The desired result would look something like this:

1. Content fades out (200ms)
2. Animating content container height change (200ms)
3. New content fades in (200ms)

Comment: You may use [Angular Animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations#introduction-to-angular-animations)

Comment: Thanks! Can you please be a little more specific?

Comment: You should create an angular animation and attach it to the element you would like to animate. You may animate the opacity to get a fade in/out animation. The link shows how to do it.

Comment: Incredibly I need the same, to avoid rendering issues on internet explorer.

Comment: @Sampgun you can disable animation (as a temporary solution). Please share if you find an answer to my question, I’ll be sure to do the same ;-)

Comment: Yeah I already new how to disable animation...